Make a "predicate" of an elytra (Minecraft)
I am looking at this: I want to Make a predicate item with the custom Model ID 991 of an vanilla elytra and add a custom texture to The "custom_elytra_one". I added it to The datapack folder -> models and added the texture to "textures" with the Name "custom_elytra_one" as said. I loaded it into a Ressource pack and added it to minecraft vanilla 1.20.4 on my Server. It doesnt load and doesnt give me the item even with the /give elytra {CustomModelData:991} command. It works with a diamond SWORD tho.. is it because of the "Broken Attribute"?
Can someone help?

Welcome on StackOverflow. Your post seems off-topic for SO as it's not related to programming. You should more go to Arqade or on some minecraft forum
